# Unordered list elements won't position

Tags: html, css

I recently built a slide-out menu using jQuery, but the list containing the menu items has been behaving strangely. No matter how I change the CSS, the various list elements always stay in the same place, right on top of each other. The page in question is [this.](http://budbranchblossom.com)

```
.slide-menu {
width: 30%;
left: -30%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
background-color: white;
}

.dlink {
   font-size: 16px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 30%;
   display: block;
}

#slide-list{
    list-style: none;
    top: 0%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.sli-list-item {
    width: 30%;
}

#slide-panel {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
}
```

This is the relevant CSS.

Comment: Please post your code here, a link to a jsfiddle would be good, too.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `.dlink` class to this:

```
.dlink {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
}
```

`position: absolute;` made them line up on top of each other.

Comment: +1 beat me to the punch. It would also probably make sense to remove the `slide-menu` class from all these links

Comment: Thanks! I could've sworn I'd tried that earlier, guess not.

Comment: Yeah that class definitely doesn't need to be there, just forgot to remove it.